# How to solve integral equation

Tags: integration, systems-of-equations, conditional-probability

Following the [color intensity problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3487016/how-to-calculate-expectation-precisely) I'm trying to solve.

I came up with the conditional probability (given the ratio of intensities $x_0$ what is the probability that the next ratio $X_1$ will be, in case two balls are still of different colors)
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1 < x | X_0 = x_0) = 
\begin{cases}
2 \cdot \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^{xy}\frac{1}{x_0+1} \cdot \frac{1}{x_0+1} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\mathop{\mathrm{d}y},\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\,\,\,\, x_0 >x \\
2 \cdot \left[\int\limits_0^{x_0 / x}\int\limits_0^{xy} \frac{1}{x_0+1} \cdot \frac{1}{x_0+1} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}+\int\limits_{x_0/x}^{1}\int\limits_0^{x_0}\frac{1}{x_0+1} \cdot \frac{1}{x_0+1} \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}\right],\qquad x_0 \leq x
\end{cases}
$$

where $2$ - comes from two ways of assigning different colors to two balls. W.l.o.g. I assumed blue ball previous intensity is $1$, and red ball had intensity $x_0$, i.e. new intensities should be uniformly picked from $[-1, x_0]$.

Solving,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_1 < x | X_0 = x_0) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{(x_0+1)^2},\qquad\qquad\qquad\,\,\, x_0 >x \\
\frac{2}{(x_0+1)^2} \left[x_0 - \frac{x_0^2}{2x}\right],\qquad x_0 \leq x
\end{cases}
$$

Taking a derivative I can calculate a pdf,
$$
f_{x_0}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(x_0+1)^2},\qquad\,\,\,\, x_0 > x \\
\frac{x_0^2}{x^2(x_0+1)^2},\qquad x_0 \leq x
\end{cases}
$$

Now, denote the expected number of steps until both balls are colored in the same color as $g(x_0)$ for the initial ratio of intensities $x_0$. Then we get an equation
$$
g(x_0) = 1 + \int\limits_0^{\infty} f_{x_0} (x) g(x) \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}
$$

> My question is, how can I solve this integral equation to get $g(x)$?

Comment: The value of the function $\;g\;$ in $\;x_0\;$ is defined evaluating an integral which depends...on $\;g\;$ itself? I don't get this...

Comment: @DonAntonio, exactly. I'm looking for a function, that is a solution for such an equation. Note, that equation should hold in each point on $(0, \infty)$.